# How do I get the active PHP file to run in Microsoft Visual Code?

Tags: php

I've managed to install Microsoft Visual Code and also XAMPP on my local drive.  I added the following line to my settings.json file 'c:/xampp/php/php.exe'.  However, when I open a PHP file and click run Chrome is launched and the index.php file is run but not the active PHP file.  So how would I get Visual Code Studio to launch my active file?

My launch.json file is as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        

        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:80",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I presume there must be some line I add to this file to get Visual Studio Code to launch my active file rather than the default index.php file but I haven't figured out what yet.

I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks and regards

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Here is my json config of VS Code, which executing currently opened script:

```
  {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000,
        "runtimeExecutable":"C:/PHP/php.exe"
    }
```

Change path to Your actual php folder.